# Combinatorics question on number of integer solutions given different restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_5 = 20$$

(a) With $x_i \leq 10$?

(b) With $x_i \leq 8$?

(c) With $x_1 = 2x_2$?

Here is what I did:

(a) ${24\choose 4} - 5{14\choose 4}$

I did this by assigning $10$ to an $x_i$ and then going from there. I subtracted this case from the total number of cases to get the number of desired cases.

I'm thinking this should rather be ${24\choose 4} - 5{13\choose 4}$ but I am not sure...I think this because maybe I should have assigned $11$ to an $x_i$ rather than $10$ and then subtracted this from the total number of ways.

(b) $5{15\choose 3} - 4{6\choose 3}$

I'm also confused with my own work for this one. I originally assigned $8$ to an $x_i$ and got rid of this variable from consideration. Then I had $12$ remaining for $n$ and $3$ for $m$ so I had ${15\choose 3}$ outcomes. Then I subtracted the case in which another variable received $9$ or more so I assigned $9$ to another variable. And then I had $3$ remaining for $n$ and $3$ for $m$, so I had ${6\choose 3}$. Since there were $4$ candidates for the greater than $8$ votes I used ${4\choose 1}$.

(c) I really need help with this part, I'm not even sure where to start...

Comment: This is a great question! I'm stumped as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$$ if $x_i \leq 10$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$?

Without restrictions, the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20 \tag{1}$$
is
$$\binom{20 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{24}{4}$$
as you found.  The condition is violated if one of the five variables exceeds $10$.  Note that at most one of the variables can exceed $10$ since $2 \cdot 11 = 22 > 20$.

Choose which of the five variables violates the condition.  Since the equation is symmetric with respect to the variables, we may suppose it is $x_1$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 11$.  Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 9 \tag{2}$$
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{9 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{13}{4}$$
Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{13}{4}$$
solutions that violate the restrictions.

Hence, there are 
$$\binom{24}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{13}{4}$$
admissible solutions, so your second attempt was right.

> How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$$ if $x_i \leq 8$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$?

In this case, at most two of the variables could exceed the restrictions since $2 \cdot 9 = 18 < 20 < 27 = 3 \cdot 9$.

Choose which of the five variables exceeds the restriction.  Since the equation is symmetric with respect to the variables, we may suppose it is $x_1$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 9$.  Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 9$ for $x_1$ in  equation 1 and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 11 \tag{3}$$
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{11 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{15}{4}$$
solutions.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{4}$$
cases in which one of the variables violates a restriction.

However, if we subtract this from the total, we will have subtracted too much since we have counted each case in which two of the variables violate a restriction twice, once for each way we could have designated one of the variables as the one that violates a restriction.  Therefore, we need to add these cases back.

There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select which two of the five variables violates a restriction.  Since the equation is symmetric with respect to the variables, we may suppose they are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 9$ and $x_2' = x_2 - 9$.  Substituting $x_1' + 9$ for $x_1$ and $x_2' + 9$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 and simplifying yields
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 2 \tag{4}$$
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{2 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{6}{4}$$
solutions.  Thus, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$
cases in which two of the restrictions are violated.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of admissible solutions is 
$$\binom{24}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$

> How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$$ if $x_i \leq 8$ if $x_1 = 2x_2$?

Consider cases.

1. If $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$.
2. If $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 1$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 17$.
3. If $x_1 = 4$ and $x_2 = 2$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 14$.
4. If $x_1 = 6$ and $x_2 = 3$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 11$.
5. If $x_1 = 8$ and $x_2 = 4$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 8$.
6. If $x_1 = 10$ and $x_2 = 5$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5$.
7. If $x_1 = 12$ and $x_2 = 6$, then $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 2$.